# VBA IFERROR to VLOOKUP referencing another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to insert this excel formula into a VBA code:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,'Manual Flags'!$F$2:$L$902,7,0),"")
```

Essentially, my main worksheet named "ContractOrganization" needs to also pull/reference data using vlookup from another worksheet named "Manual Flags" and cells (F2 to L902) and print the result into cell L2

I tried adding a vba code below and I set my worksheets and variables ahead of time to try and clean the code, but nothing is working.

How can I reference another worksheet within a formula in vba using iferror and vlookup?

```
Sub AddFormula_ManualFlag()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim result As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manual Flags")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ContractOrganization")
Set rng = ws2.Range("L2")

On Error Resume Next 'add this because if value is not found, vlookup fails, you get 1004
result = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ws2.Range("E2"),ws1.Range("$F$2:$L$902").Value,7,0),"""")"

rng.Formula = result


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

first remove the `On Error Resume Next`, it is not needed when you are putting the formula in the cell itself, only when using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`.

Any vba needs to be removed from the quotes and concatenated with `&`:

```
result = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & ws2.Range("E2").Address(0,0) & "," & ws1.Range("$F$2:$L$902").Address(1,1,,1) & ",7,0),"""")"
```